# Существуют ли готовые подобия прокси-серверов для пересылки сокетов?

Tags: java, сокет

Задача следующая: существует несколько маленьких серверов с Java приложением, которые по одному сокету на сервер связываются с центральным сервером, нужно между ними поставить еще один сервер, который будет переправлять через себя сокеты. Простые прокси или VPN использовать невозможно, т.к. в обращении с маленького сервера будет компрометирован IP основного, а если просто написать Java приложение, которое примет соединение и откроет еще одно с основным, - это очень перегружает систему. Может, уже существуют решения подобного рода?

Comment: а разве Ваше приложение на java не будет той же прокси? Разве в этом случае не будет "компроментироваться IP"?

Comment: Маленький сервер партнера доступен партнеру, так что будет

Comment: а почему "партнер" не может поставить себе прокси?

Comment: Суть в том что Java приложение на сайте партнера должно иметь соединение с основным Java сервером, но партнер не должен знать реального IP адреса этого Java cервера, поскольку основной сервер держит сразу же пару тысяч партнеров, любые попытки атаки на него могут быть очень губительны для инфраструктуры, а если на каждые к примеру 100 партнеров будет выделен отдельный "прокси" сервер, то в случае особо активных атак, с которыми не справится фаерволл, упадет только часть инфраструктуры.

Comment: @Максим Поздняков, говоря, "будет переправлять через себя сокеты", Вы подразумеваете данные, которые передаются по сокетам?

Т.е. то, что основной сервер не будет знать *истинные* IP клиентов (если их нет в данных) Вас не смущает.

Comment: Да я имел в виду, конечно, данные, IP адреса не важны, авторизация происходит по ключам доступа к API и на "прокси" сервере будет реализован whitelist как дополнительная мера безопасности

Comment: Наверное, что-нибудь [из этого](http://www.opennet.ru/prog/sml/14.shtml) подойдет.